# Perturbation of sum of convex functions

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $f_1,\ldots,f_n:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ be convex functions, and $f=\sum_{i} f_i$. Assume each $f_i$ has a unique minimum $x^*_i$, and also assume $f$ has a unique minimum $x^*$.
Let $g_1,\ldots,g_n:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ be convex functions, such that $f_i(x)=g_i(x)$ if $\|x-x^*_i\|\geq 1$, and $f_i(x)\leq g_i(x)$ if $\|x-x^*_i\|\leq 1$  where $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm. Let $g=\sum_{i} g_i$.

Does there exists a minimum $x'^*$ of $g$, such that $\|x^*-x'^*\|\leq 2$?

Intuitively, we want to show a small perturbation of each function around the minimum only change the minimum of the sum of the perturbed functions by a small amount.

Answer (score 1):

We do not need the structure that $f$ and $g$ are sums of $n$ convex function, one convex function is enough.

Wlog assume $x^*:=0$. We can achieve this by replacing $f$ with $f(\cdot + x^*)$. Now $f$ has global unique minimum  at $x^*=0$.

Let $x$ be such that $\|x\|\ge1$. Then by convexity
$$
f( \frac{x}{\|x\|}) \le \frac1{\|x\|} f(x) + (1-\frac1{\|x\|})f(0).
$$
Let $m$ be the minimum of $f$ on the unit sphere. Since $f$ has a unique global minimum this implies $m>f(0)$. Using $m$ in the above inequality yields
$$
\|x\|(m-f(0)) \le f(x) - f(0).
$$
Hence $f(x)\to \infty$ if $\|x\|\to \infty$. Since $g$ coincides with $f$ for points $x$ with $\|x\|\ge1$, the same property is true for $g$.

This implies that $g$ has a global minimum $x'$. Here we use that convexity of $g$ implies continuity. If $\|x'\|>1$ then it would be a local minimum of $f$ as well, which cannot happen. Hence $\|x'\|\le 1$.

So we proved that $g$ has a global minimum, and all global minima of $g$  have distance $\le1$ to $x^*$.

The extreme case is the following example: $n=1$, $f(x)=x^2$, $g(x) = \max(1,f(x))$. Then $x^*=0$ but every point in $[-1,1]$ is a global minimum of $g$.